# Map function with index as one of arguments in LISP

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Is there any built-in function in LISP languages (or Racket in particular) that would work like map, but pass index of the element as one of the arguments to the mapping function?

Example of such function would be:

```
(define map-index (lambda (func list)
  (map func list (build-list (length list) (lambda (i) i)))))

;usage:
> (map-index cons '(a b c d))
;output:
'((a . 0) (b . 1) (c . 2) (d . 3))
```

Obviously this is not a very efficient implementation and doesn't support multiple lists as arguments, like regular map does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but there are other things for similar goals, like [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) with [`in-naturals`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-naturals%29%29) or [`in-indexed`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-indexed%29%29).

For example instead of `(map-index f lst)`, the pattern would be

```
(for/list ([x lst] [i (in-naturals)]) (f x i))
```

or

```
(for/list ([(x i) (in-indexed lst)]) (f x i))
```

And either of those patterns could be used to implement `map-index` as well as your combination of `map` and `build-list`.

Racket's iteration forms like [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) are more flexible than a fixed set of map-like functions.

Concrete Examples:

```
> (for/list ([x '(a b c d)] [i (in-naturals)]) (cons x i))
'((a . 0) (b . 1) (c . 2) (d . 3))
> (for/list ([(x i) (in-indexed '(a b c d))]) (cons x i))
'((a . 0) (b . 1) (c . 2) (d . 3))
```

Or if you still want a `map-index` function you could define it more succinctly using this.

```
> (define (map-index f lst)
    (for/list ([(x i) (in-indexed lst)]) (f x i)))
> (map-index cons '(a b c d))
'((a . 0) (b . 1) (c . 2) (d . 3))
```

Answer (score 5):

---

## Racket

---

You can write a dead-simple version of `map-index` using the Racket `range` procedure and mapping over the result:

```
(define (map-index-1 f xs)
  (map f xs (range (length xs))))
```

In some situations you might want the indices first:

```
(define (map-index-2 f xs)
  (map f (range (length xs)) xs))
```

If you want to be able to use `map-index` over multiple lists, you can pass the list arguments to an optional parameter. Here, `apply` applies the `map` procedure to a list constructed from the function `f`, the input lists, and a `range` list:

```
(define (map-index-3 f . xs)
  (apply map (cons f
                   (append xs
                           (list (range (length (car xs))))))))
```

But it might make more sense to place the indices first when mapping over multiple lists:

```
(define (map-index-4 f . xs)
  (apply map (cons f
                   (cons (range (length (car xs)))
                         xs))))
```

```
scratch.rkt> (map-index-1 cons '(a b c d))
'((a . 0) (b . 1) (c . 2) (d . 3))

scratch.rkt> (map-index-2 cons '(a b c d))
'((0 . a) (1 . b) (2 . c) (3 . d))

scratch.rkt> (map-index-3 list '(a b c d) '(one two three four) '(w x y z))
'((a one w 0) (b two x 1) (c three y 2) (d four z 3))

scratch.rkt> (map-index-4 list '(a b c d) '(one two three four) '(w x y z))
'((0 a one w) (1 b two x) (2 c three y) (3 d four z))
```

---

## Scheme

---

Standard Scheme does not have a built-in `range` procedure, but it is easy enough to write a simple version. These solutions will work on any R4RS, R5RS, R6RS, or R7RS Scheme implementation. This version of `range` does more than is required for the current application, taking a `step` argument which can be positive or negative:

```
(define (range start stop step)
  (if (or (and (> step 0)
               (>= start stop))
          (and (<= step 0)
               (<= start stop)))
      '()
      (cons start (range (+ start step) stop step))))
```

Having defined a `range` procedure, the same approach used for the Racket solutions above can be used in Scheme:

```
(define (map-index-5 f xs)
  (map f xs (range 0 (length xs) 1)))

(define (map-index-6 f xs)
  (map f (range 0 (length xs) 1) xs))

(define (map-index-7 f . xs)
  (apply map (cons f
                   (append xs
                           (list (range 0 (length (car xs)) 1))))))

(define (map-index-8 f . xs)
  (apply map (cons f
                   (cons (range 0 (length (car xs)) 1)
                         xs))))
```

```
> (map-index-5 cons '(a b c d))
((a . 0) (b . 1) (c . 2) (d . 3))

> (map-index-6 cons '(a b c d))
((0 . a) (1 . b) (2 . c) (3 . d))

> (map-index-7 list '(a b c d) '(one two three four) '(w x y z))
((a one w 0) (b two x 1) (c three y 2) (d four z 3))

> (map-index-8 list '(a b c d) '(one two three four) '(w x y z))
((0 a one w) (1 b two x) (2 c three y) (3 d four z))
```

---

## A `map-range` Procedure for Standard Scheme

---

This method can be extended to use numbers in a more complex range that may not represent indices by taking advantage of the capabilities of a `range` function. Using the `range` definition from above, this `map-range` procedure still works on R4RS to R7RS Scheme implementations:

```
(define (map-range f start step . xs)
  (let ((stop (+ start (* step (length (car xs))))))
    (apply map (cons f
                     (cons (range start stop step)
                           xs)))))
```

```
> (map-range cons 2 2 '(a b c d))
((2 . a) (4 . b) (6 . c) (8 . d))

> (map-range list 5 5 '(a b c d) '(one two three four) '(w x y z))
((5 a one w) (10 b two x) (15 c three y) (20 d four z))

> (map-range cons 2 -2 '(a b c d))
((2 . a) (0 . b) (-2 . c) (-4 . d))

> (map-range list 5 -5 '(a b c d) '(one two three four) '(w x y z))
((5 a one w) (0 b two x) (-5 c three y) (-10 d four z))
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborate answer. I think for/list would be preferred in Racket, in other dialects this might be the way though. I'm just not sure about performance, AFAIK this could be implemented using foldl/foldr sacrificing readability in the process.

Comment: @AdamŠtafa -- `for/list` is not available in any other Scheme dialect AFAIK; the main reason I wrote this answer was to show how your goal might be accomplished in portable Scheme. But for the simplest case of `map-index` I would probably reach for `(map f xs (range (length xs))`, even in Racket. I personally find it more concise and legible than `(for/list ([(x i) (in-indexed lst)]) (f x i))`; I would be surprised if there is a significant performance difference, but you could always measure and compare.